# Why do my screens keep freezing

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, freeze, usb-c, dvi

I am brand new to Ubuntu. I have an Acer Nitro 17 Gaming PC. I have Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS installed as a dual boot with Windows 11. I have four Monitors Plugged in. One connected DVI to USB-C, one connected via HDMI. The other two are plugged in a GIQ Docking station via HDMI which is connected to a USB 3.0 port on the laptop.

My two screens that are plugged in directly to the Laptop (not through the docking station) freeze randomly (no mouse or keyboard movement), but I can still use the other screens two screens and right click to open the terminal, but after a while the entire laptop freezes and I have to reboot the laptop. I am using the NVIDIA driver metapackage 535 (Proprietary, Tested). I have tried switching to the other NVIDIA drivers options listed but when I do some or all of the monitors stop working. When I switch to Windows I have no issues and all the monitors run smoothly. I am thinking of switching to another Linux distro but before I did I figured I’d ask for some help first.